# How can I create a list that can hold objects of different types?

Tags: delphi

I am currently using a generic list typed like this:

```
List: TList<TPoint>;
```

I would like for `List` to be able to hold, as an alternative, points with three coordinates:

```
type 
  TPoint3D = record 
    x, y, z: Integer;
  end;
```

I'd like to declare something like this:

```
List: TList<TCanBeEitherTPointOrTPoint3D>;
```

Naturally this won't work, but I don't know what will work!

Comment: I took the liberty of re-writing the question to express what I think you are asking. Did I get it right?

Comment: yes, the rewriting is correct,  according to my research I need a TObjectList to store different data types inside one List

Answer (score 9):

Delphi does not support lists of heterogeneous types. You have to be able to represent *all* the potential values with a single type. One way to do that is by joining all the different types into a single discriminated union:

```
type
  TPointUnion = record
    case NumDimensions: Integer of
      2: (p2: TPoint);
      3: (p3: TPoint3D);
  end;
```

Then you can declare a list of that type:

```
var
  List: TList<TPointUnion>;
```

You can add values of type `TPointUnion` to the list. To construct a value of that type, simply assign the `NumDimensions` field, and then assign the corresponding `p2` or `p3` field. When reading such a value, check the `NumDimensions` field to discover which point field holds a valid value. In practice, `p2` is always safe to use since its fields overlap with the corresponding fields of `p3`.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could use classe types instead of the [record type with variant parts](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Structured_Types#Variant_Parts_in_Records) as [Rob suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15670280/757830):

```
type
  TPoint2D = class(TObject)
    X: Integer;
    Y: Integer;
  end;

  TPoint3D = class(TPoint2D)
    Z: Integer;
  end;

var
  List: TList<TPoint2D>;

begin
  if List[I] is TPoint2D then
    TPoint2D(List[I]).X := 10
  else
    TPoint3D(List[I]).Z := 10;
```

I do not exactly know whether this approach will perform better<strike>, but memory usage would be the same</strike>.

Comment: As of Delphi 2009, `SizeOf(TPointUnion) <= TPoint2D.InstanceSize < TPoint3D.InstanceSize`. Objects are bigger than you think they are.

Comment: I would not imagine performance and memory are particularly important here. I would expect that convenience for the coder is the no. 1 design driver.

Answer (score 1):

System.RTTI.TValue may help:

```
type
  tAnyList = tList<TValue>;  // Generic TList of TValue

procedure testTAnyList;
var
  tal: tAnyList;
  pt3d: TPoint3D;
  pt2d: TPoint2D;
begin
  // Init pt3d, pt2d here
  tal := tAnyList.Create;
  try
    tal.Add('Some Text');        // Store text
    tal.Add(16);                 // Some integer
    tal.Add(form1);              // Object
    tal.Add(tValue.From(pt3d));  // TPoint3D record
    tal.Add(tValue.From(pt2d));  // TPoint2D record
  finally
    tal.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Note when using records: pt3d will be passed as value (i.e. it's values will be copied), not by reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
program MultiClass;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Generics.Defaults, Generics.Collections;

type

  TPoint2D = class
    x, y: integer;
    constructor create(x, y: integer);
  end;

  TPoint3D = class
    x, y, z: integer;
    constructor create(x, y, z: integer);
  end;

  TPointSelector = (ePoint2D, ePoint3D);

  TPoint2DOrTPoint3D = class
    select: TPointSelector;
    obj: Pointer;
    constructor create(myClass: TPoint2D); overload;
    constructor create(myClass: TPoint3D); overload;
    constructor create(x, y: integer); overload;
    constructor create(x, y, z: integer); overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

Constructor TPoint2D.create(x: integer; y: integer);
begin
  self.x := x;
  self.y := y;
end;

Constructor TPoint3D.create(x: integer; y: integer; z: integer);
begin
  self.x := x;
  self.y := y;
  self.z := y;
end;

constructor TPoint2DOrTPoint3D.create(x, y: integer);
begin
  select := ePoint2D;
  obj := TPoint2D.create(x, y);
end;

constructor TPoint2DOrTPoint3D.create(x, y, z: integer);
begin
  select := ePoint3D;
  obj := TPoint3D.create(x, y, z);
end;

constructor TPoint2DOrTPoint3D.create(myClass: TPoint2D);
begin
  select := ePoint2D;
  obj := TPoint2D;
end;

constructor TPoint2DOrTPoint3D.create(myClass: TPoint3D);
begin
  select := ePoint3D;
  obj := TPoint3D;
end;

destructor TPoint2DOrTPoint3D.Destroy;
begin
  if assigned(obj) then
    case select of
      ePoint2D:
        TPoint2D(obj).Free;
      ePoint3D:
        TPoint3D(obj).Free;
    end;
end;

procedure Test;
var
  PointList: TObjectList<TPoint2DOrTPoint3D>;
  I: integer;
  Pt: TPoint2DOrTPoint3D;
  P3D: TPoint3D;
  P2D: TPoint2D;
begin
  PointList := TObjectList<TPoint2DOrTPoint3D>.create;
  PointList.OwnsObjects := true;

  PointList.Add(TPoint2DOrTPoint3D.create(10, 10));
  PointList.Add(TPoint2DOrTPoint3D.create(50, 10));
  PointList.Add(TPoint2DOrTPoint3D.create(-10, 10, 90));
  PointList.Add(TPoint2DOrTPoint3D.create(3, 50, 70));

  for Pt in PointList do
  begin
    case Pt.select of
      ePoint2D:
        begin
          P2D := Pt.obj;
          writeln(P2D.x, '  ', P2D.y);
        end;
      ePoint3D:
        begin
          P3D := Pt.obj;
          writeln(P3D.x, '  ', P3D.y, '  ', P3D.z);
        end;
    end;
  end;

  PointList.Destroy;

end;

begin
  try
    Test;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  readln;

end.
```

This is maybe a bit of overkill but I thought it might be relevant

programmed in Delphi XE